# Filter text column based on keywords vector

Tags: r, string, dplyr, stringi

Here is the `dput()` info

```
structure(list(Text = c("bandwidth issues. issues with vpn", 
"be more customer focussed reduce prices and offer same deas to existing customers that they use to attract new ones", 
"be more helpful and provide a better service.", "better customer service", 
"better customer service and products", "better customer service more transparency competency", 
"better customer service uk based. greater reliability and customer support", 
"better customer service. a more coherent ad that is better explained.", 
"better customer services", "better customer services and they could be truthful"
)), .Names = "Text", row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to `filter` those rows based on the keywords in a `vector`.

This is what I have tried so far but don't understand why it still brings the other `text` which dont have a match:

```
phrase = c("staff","agent","advisor","english","foreign","indian","gentleman","lady","man","woman","people","uk",
       "speak","supervisor","manager","spoke","spoken","non-uk","representative","he","she")

phrase_match <- str_c(phrase, collapse = "|")

brand_nps_filtered%>%
              filter(str_detect(Text, phrase_match))
```

As you can see it brings the `be more customer focused reduce prices and offer same deas to existing customers that they use to attract new ones` which don't have any associated keyword in the `phrase`

Comment: I think you need to add word boundaries, something like `df[grepl(paste(paste0('\\b', phrase, '\\b'), collapse = '|'), df$Text),]`

Comment: what does the `\\b` do ?

Comment: I have tried with `grepl` the results are the same.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper It's a boundary for words. Check it this : http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: it works for me, returning only the 4th line `better customer service uk based. greater reliability and customer support` because of `"uk"`

Comment: thank you @Mbr Mbr

Comment: @Shery your code matches too much because for example "he" matches "they", with these magical `\\b`s they don't match anymore

Comment: @Sotos this has saved the day... it works! thank you guys

Comment: Good. I will find a dupe to close this with then.